# How to add icons to QMenu in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt-creator, qt-designer, qmenu, qaction, qicon

I have several *.png icon files like new.png, open.png etc. I added these icons to my main menu in the QtCreator as following:

1. Click on corresponding QAction in desgin mode
2. In that actions property window --> QAction --> icon --> Select file...
3. Select e.g. new.png
4. Enter

Now, I can see that icon next to the newAction QAction object in the Qt creator design mode as here [image]

The *visible* and *iconVisibleInMenu* is both checked in the properties window!

But, when I build that project and run my application, the icon is not there?? Why or what am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok 
1. I have to add a resource file via right click -> add.. -> Qt -> Resource file
2. Click on that new resource file and add folder with the icons.

Now, you are also able to select a resource in your whole code.